# python and openpyxl : how to replace new occurence of a date on excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel sheet containing data on two columns (A & B) like that :

| A | B | (FYI) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | orange | ("couple 1") |
| tomato | carrot | ("couple 2") |
| banana | kiwi | ("couple 3") |
| orange | apple | ("couple 1" new occurence) |
| tomato | carrot | ("couple 2" new occurence) |
| salad | eggplant | ("couple 4") |

I want to replace every new occurence of a same "couple" by à 0 (zero), like that :

| A | B | (FYI) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | orange | ("couple 1") |
| tomato | carrot | ("couple 2") |
| banana | kiwi | ("couple 3") |
| 0 | 0 |  |
| 0 | 0 |  |
| salad | eggplant | ("couple 4") |

i taught that a simple code like this one would be ok :

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import *
import numpy
from numpy import *

wb = load_workbook("Desktop/programme/wb.xlsx")

ws = wb["Sheet"]

stop_row = ws.max_row + 1

for n1 in range(1,stop_row) :

    for n2 in range(2,stop_row) :

        item_a = ws.cell(row=n1, column=1).value
        item_b = ws.cell(row=n1, column=2).value

        item_1 = ws.cell(row=n2, column=1).value
        item_2 = ws.cell(row=n2, column=2).value

        if (item_a == item_1 and item_b == item_2) or (item_a == item_2 and item_b == item_1) :

            ws.cell(row=n2, column=1).value = 0
            ws.cell(row=n2, column=2).value = 0
```

But what i get is :

| A | B | (FYI) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | orange | ("couple 1") |
| 0 | 0 | ("couple 2") |
| 0 | 0 | ("couple 3") |
| 0 | 0 | ("couple 1" new occurence) |
| 0 | 0 | ("couple 2" new occurence) |
| 0 | 0 | ("couple 4") |

any idea why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First iteration, n1 = 1 and n2 = 1. The values `item_1` and `item_a` will be the same with that setup because they're pointing to the same cell. Same thing with `item_2` and `item_b`. Perhaps your second loop should be `range(n1 + 1, stop_row)` ? Don't worry if n1 + 1 goes larger than stop_row; it just won't count anything instead of looping around.

Also, be aware if you do this, you'll have to start n1 from 0, otherwise the first row will never be considered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Actually it is a mistake in my example (i am editing it). n1 was actually equal to 1 and n2 to 2 but i still have the same result...
As for the start, i think that openpyxl starts from 1 (contrary to xlrd which starts from 0).

Comment: I've actually just understood that i had to literally put "range(n1 + 1, stop_row)" !!! Thank you very much !!